# Showing that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh ax}{\sinh \pi x} \, \cos bx \, dx = \frac{\sin a}{\cos a + \cosh b}$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

I want to show that $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh ax}{\sinh \pi x} \, \cos bx \, dx = \frac{\sin a}{\cos a + \cosh b} \, , \quad -\pi < a < \pi . $$

I tried integrating $f \displaystyle (z) = e^{ibz} \, \frac{\sinh az}{\sinh \pi z} $ around an indented rectangular contour with vertices at $\pm R, \pm R+ i$.

I  ended up with  the equation $$ (1+ e^{-b} \cos a) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh ax}{\sinh \pi x} \, \cos bx \, dx  - e^{-b}\sin a \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cosh ax}{\sinh \pi x} \, \sin bx \ dx = e^{-b} \sin a . $$

But I don't see how to extract the value of the integral from this equation.

Did I integrate the wrong function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77172/calculating-the-fourier-transform-of-frac-sinhkx-sinhx). I think the contour used by Sasha in his answer yields a very nice solution. It's certainly much cleaner! ;)

Comment: Thanks.  It's essentially the same problem.  But how did he evaluate that infinite series?

Comment: $(-1)^n e^{-n\pi\omega}\sin(\pi \kappa n)$ is the imaginary part of $\exp(-n\pi \omega + i \pi \kappa n + i\pi n) = e^{-n\pi  (\omega +i (\kappa + 1))}$, which is a geometric series.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a simple way to calculate your old question. Note
$$  \frac{\sinh(ax)}{\sinh(\pi x)} \cos(bx) = \frac{\sinh(ax)}{\sinh(\pi x)}\cosh(ibx)=\frac{\sinh((a+bi)x)+\sinh((a-bi)x)}{\sinh(\pi x)} $$
and 
$$ \int_0^\infty\frac{\sinh(ax)}{\sinh(bx)}dx=\frac{\pi}{2b}\tan\frac{a\pi}{2b}. $$
So
\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\int_0^\infty\frac{\sinh(ax)}{\sinh(\pi x)} \cos(bx)dx\\
&=&\int_0^\infty\frac{\sinh((a+bi)x)+\sin((a-bi)x)}{\sinh(\pi x)}dx\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\tan\frac{a+bi}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\tan\frac{a-bi}{2}\\
&=&\frac{\sin a}{\cos a + \cosh b}.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 8):

I indeed integrated the wrong function.

Integrating $ \displaystyle f(z) = \frac{e^{(a+ib)z}}{\sinh \pi z}$ around the same contour, we get

$$ \begin{align} \text{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx + e^{-b}e^{ia} \ \text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx &= \pi i \, \text{Res}[f(z),0] + \pi i \ \text{Res}[f(z),i]\\ &= i \, \left(1-e^{-b}e^{ia} \right) . \end{align} $$

Therefore,

$$ \text{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)  \ dx = i \, \frac{1-e^{-b} e^{ia}}{1+e^{-b}e^{ia}} = \frac{\sin a}{\cos a + \cosh b} + i \, \frac{\sinh b}{\cos a + \cosh b} .$$

But notice that $$ \begin{align} \text{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx &= \text{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cosh ax}{\sinh \pi x} \, \cos bx \, dx + i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cosh ax}{\sinh \pi x} \, \sin bx \, dx + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh ax}{\sinh \pi x} \,  \cos bx \, dx \\ &+ i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh ax}{ \sinh \pi x} \, \sin bx \, dx \\ &= 0 + i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cosh ax}{\sinh \pi x} \, \sin bx \, dx + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh ax}{\sinh \pi x} \, \cos bx \, dx + 0 \\ &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh ax}{\sinh \pi x} \, \cos bx   \, dx + i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cosh ax}{\sinh \pi x} \, \sin bx   \, dx . \end{align}$$

Equating the real parts on both sides of the equation, we get $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh ax}{\sinh \pi x} \,\cos bx \, dx= \frac{\sin a}{\cos a + \cosh b}.$$

And equating the imaginary parts on both sides of the equation, we get $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cosh ax}{\sinh \pi x} \, \sin bx \, dx = \frac{\sinh b}{\cos a + \cosh b}.$$