# Contour integral of $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sinh(kx)}{\sinh(x)}dx = \frac{1}{2}\tan{\frac{a}{2}}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

From [Calculating the Fourier transform of $\frac{\sinh(kx)}{\sinh(x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77172/calculating-the-fourier-transform-of-frac-sinhkx-sinhx)

In the case of zero $\omega$ and integral starts as 0, how do I prove that using contour integral

$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sinh(kx)}{\sinh(x)}dx = \frac{1}{2}\tan{\frac{k}{2}}$, $|k|<1$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: u mean $\tan(k/2)$ right....

Comment: yes. thank you.

Comment: any own thoughts?

Comment: so i try to integrate using a rectangle excluding the point of 0 and i as after I using the exponential identities they seem to be the pole at the denominator.

Comment: i would try to use the parity of the integrand to make the domain of integration the whole real axis. furthermore you don't have to avoid zero because the singularity there is removeable

Answer (score 1):

For any $a\in(-1,1)$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}^+$ the identity
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sinh(ax)e^{-kx}\,dx = \frac{a}{k^2-a^2} \tag{1}$$
holds trivially, so by expanding $\frac{1}{\sinh x}$ as a geometric series we have that 
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sinh(ax)}{\sinh(x)}\,dx=\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{2a}{(2m+1)^2-a^2}\tag{2} $$
but the RHS of $(2)$ is a well-known series, which can be obtained by applying $\frac{d}{dz}\log(\ldots)$ to the Weierstrass product for the cosine function, or by just invoking [Herglotz' trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581162/how-does-the-herglotz-trick-work). The final outcome is
$$\forall a\in(-1,1),\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sinh(ax)}{\sinh(x)}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\tan\left(\frac{\pi a}{2}\right).\tag{3} $$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sinh\pars{kx} \over \sinh\pars{x}} & =
\mrm{sgn}\pars{k}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 - \expo{-2\verts{k}x} \over 1 - \expo{-2x}}
\expo{-\pars{1 - \verts{k}}x}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\mbox{It converges whenever}\ \color{red}{\verts{k} < 1}}}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\expo{-2x}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over 2}\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{k}\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{\verts{k}} \over 1 - x}\, x^{-1/2 - \verts{k}/2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{k}\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{-1/2 + \verts{k}/2} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{-1/2 - \verts{k}/2} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{k}\bracks{%
\Psi\pars{{1 \over 2} + {\verts{k} \over 2}} -
\Psi\pars{{1 \over 2} - {\verts{k} \over 2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{k}\pi
\cot\pars{\pi\bracks{{1 \over 2} - {\verts{k} \over 2}}} =
{1 \over 2}\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{k}\tan\pars{{\pi \over 2}\,\verts{k}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{1 \over 2}\,\tan\pars{{\pi \over 2}\,k}\,,\qquad \verts{k} < 1}
\end{align}