# Abel's Integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\sinh(\pi x)(1+x^2)} \,dx$

Tags: improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

According to Wolfram Alpha, "Abel's Integral" is the following, and it's value is found in the method indicated below. I am unable to see how line 6 is obtained. $$$$ [image]

Comment: Due to the Abel-Plana formula for alternating sums, the integral equals (setting $f(t)=\frac{1}{2(1+t)}$)

$$
I=\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^n f(n)-\frac{1}{2}f(0)=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n}n-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2} \log(2)-\frac{1}{4}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{b}{{{b^2} + 1}} = \int_0^\infty  {{e^{ - bx}}\cos xdx} $$
Hence
$$\int_0^\infty  {\frac{x}{{{x^2} + 1}}{e^{ - ax}}dx}  = \int_0^\infty  {\int_0^\infty  {{e^{ - xt}}(\cos t){e^{ - ax}}dt} dx}  = \int_0^\infty  {\frac{{\cos t}}{{t + a}}dt}$$
this gives
$$\text{Ci}(\pi n) = {( - 1)^{n + 1}}\int_0^\infty  {\frac{x}{{{x^2} + 1}}{e^{ - \pi nx}}dx}$$
Summing over $n=1,3,5...$ gives 
$$\sum_{n = 1,3,5...}\text{Ci}(\pi n) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{(x^2+1)(e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x})} dx$$

This is line 6.

---

For the evaluation of the integral, consider

$$ \mathcal{I} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\sinh(\pi x)(1+x^2)}dx $$

Consider the rectangular contour with vertices $R, R+Ri, -R+Ri, -R$, where $R=2N+1/2$ with $N$ a very large integer. When $R$ tends to infinity, the following three integrals tend to 0
$$\int_{R}^{R+Ri} \frac{x}{\sinh(\pi x)(1+x^2)}dx \to 0$$
$$\int_{R+Ri}^{-R+Ri} \frac{x}{\sinh(\pi x)(1+x^2)}dx \to 0$$
$$\int_{-R+Ri}^{-R} \frac{x}{\sinh(\pi x)(1+x^2)}dx \to 0$$

Note that the function $\dfrac{z}{\sinh(\pi z)(1+z^2)}$ has simple pole at $z=ni$, with $n\geq 2$ and a double pole at $z=i$, the residue at $z=ni$ being $\dfrac{(-1)^n(ni)}{\pi(1-n^2)}$, and at $z=i$ being $\frac{i}{4\pi}$.

Hence $$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{I} &= 2\pi i\frac{i}{4\pi} + 2\pi i\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(ni)}{\pi(1-n^2)} \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}+2\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nn}{n^2-1} \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n-1}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\right) \\
&= 2\ln 2 -1
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I apologize if this is a frustrating request, but would you mind demonstrating how one would actually go about evaluating the integral?

Comment: @BelowAverageIntelligence  I updated my answer

Comment: When you say "a double pole at n=i" do you mean at z=i?

Comment: Yes, I corrected it

Comment: Is the contour triangular?

Comment: I ask because R, R+Ri, and R-Ri all lie on the line where Re (z)=R.

Comment: Oops, it is rectangular, I corrected the typo. It should be $-R+Ri$.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the residue at z=i. Would you mind explaining how you calculate that?

Comment: Also, can you explain why the three integrals tend to zero and what the significance of that is?

Comment: And is it okay that we have a pole on the boundary of the contour at z=0?

Comment: Three last questions 1) Why do we only care about the part of complex plane where Im(z)>0? 2) What is the significance of R being equal to 2N+1/2?  and 3) Why does integrating our function over this rectangular area which spans half of the complex plane give us the integral (which doesn't seem to have that much to do with complex numbers) over the real numbers that we were aiming for? (please correct me if any of the statements I've made here are incorrect).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Parseval's theorem
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\bar{g}(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(s)\hat{\bar{g}}(s)ds $$
to evaluate this integral. Let 
$$ f(x)=\frac{x}{\sinh(\pi x)}, g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}. $$
Clearly
$$  \hat{g}(s)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-|s|}. $$
From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77172/calculating-the-fourier-transform-of-frac-sinhkx-sinhx), one has
$$ \hat{f}(s)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}\cosh^2(\frac{s}{2})}. $$
So
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\bar{g}(x)dx\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(s)\hat{\bar{g}}(s)ds\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}\cosh^2(\frac{s}{2})}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-|s|}ds\\
&=&\frac12(2\ln2-1).
\end{eqnarray}